# Choose web.py or Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I wanna build a simple social network use python. Just like twitter but smaller than twitter.I just wanna make a few features like follow,BE followed,view others profile,etc.

My question is that i should use **web.py** or **Tornado?**

BTW, is there any tutorial about Tornado? I feel it hard to understand when i read the documenations on the offical.

(Oops,my english is week. :P )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these two are different things.
Tornado is web server while web.py is a framework.
therefore you can use both of them.

Comment: but i can use tornado to make a website like web.py.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to your Q:** 
write your app with web.py  ！ I'm sure we can build a twitter copy based web.py very soon .

And then , you'd better to know these:

- web.py is a small but charp python web framework
- tornado is a web server, but also can do more things .
- The document of tornado http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/index.html is good,and I guess you want some examples ?   Click here https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/demos

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Pinax.  When I used it, it had the self-concept of 'django with an opinion.'  I'm not sure where it's at now, but my experience was that it was best suited for exactly what you want to do.  One of the base projects is actually a fully functional social network site.  You could then customize from there.